# Migrate list of huge XML files in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have the code:

```
final int numOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( numOfThreads );
final int numOfFiles = listOfAllFiles.size();
final BlockingQueue<File> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<File>( numOfFiles, false, listOfAllFiles );

for ( int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++ ) {
    exec.execute( () -> {
        File file = null;

        while ( (file = queue.poll()) != null ) {
            migrate( file );
        }
    } );
}
```

The fixed size `ExecutorService` polls (XML) files from a `BlockingQueue` in order to migrate them. Since most of the files are pretty big (multiple GBs), each thread is doing a lot of I/O.

Is the queue even necessary? Can't I just do:

```
final int numOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( numOfThreads );

for ( final File file : listOfAllFiles ) {
    exec.execute( () -> migrate( file ) );
}
```

I am also wondering if the fixed thread pool is the ideal choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that the numper is fixed, that queue does not provide any benefit. You don't need it. You would need it if new files kept coming in.

The number of threads looks valid, too. But it really depends on OS and JVM version to get the best number. You might rather do some experiments to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

An ExecutorService with a fixed sized thread pool is a good choice.  However, I think you should make the pool size a tuning parameter.

The problem is that we don't know if `migrateFile` is CPU intensive, I/O intensive, memory (heap *size*) intensive or some combination.  The optimal thread could will depend on this.  The best strategy is to do some experiments.

Answer (score 0):

In your case queue in between not solving any purpose.Before jump into coding analyze the real bottleneck  in processing large files.

Processing a file involves reading from the disk, processing (e.g. parsing an XML and transforming), and writing back to the disk.So  it is a trade off in terms of  better I/O, better CPU usage, and better memory usage. To know It is important to conduct profiling to monitor CPU usage, memory usage, and I/O efficiency.

- Reading the data from the disk can be I/O-heavy.
- Storing the read data in the Java heap memory to process them can be memory-
  heavy.
- Parsing & transforming the data can be CPU-heavy.
- Writing the processed data back to the disk can be I/O-heavy.